# Using pym.js with Github Pages won't work

Tags: javascript, pym.js

I'm setting up a Github Pages web page. I want to put some interactive charts on this page. I've made each chart in its own separate HTML file and want to use pym.js to put them on the Github Pages web page. On the `.md` page I have something like this:

```
<script src="https://pym.nprapps.org/pym.v1.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pymParent = new pym.Parent("whites","{{site.baseurl}}/charts/example.html",{});
</script>
```

​But only a 404 error page appears in the iframe when I load the page. (Dunno if this matters, but I'm testing locally by ​running `bundle exec jekyll serve`). I can open the HTML file in Firefox and see the chart, but pym-ing it fails.

Answer (score 0):

My project's root directory lacked a `charts` folder.